# Insert Json string into MsSQL with JAVA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, json

I got MsSQL server 2012 and Json string with fixed schema.

I'm trying to insert Json into the server, there must be a way to automatically parse the Json and then insert all the values.

This is how the Json look like:

```
{
    "UUID": "1408611728327",
    "accuracy": 0,
    "timestamp": 1408611668.274444000,
    "x": -2.46,
    "y": 24.779999,
    "z": -17.46
}
```

Comment: MongoDB does this automatically, but with a RDB system like mySQL, the tables have all got to be set up beforehand, and there is no way to automatically parse

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Why don't you just write a method that takes in this data, and persists it to the database? Then you have a way to automatically parse it: call the method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reformat with a regex? So it becomes like:

```
insert into my_table values ('1408611728327',0,1408611668.274444000,-2.46,24.779999,-17.46);
```

This of course assuming the table fields are in the correct order. Something like:

```
myJson.replace("{","("); // you need round brackets instead of the json style ones
myJson.replace("}",")");
myJson.replaceAll("\".*\": ([^,]*),","$1"); // drops the name of the columns, only keeps the values, comma separated
myJson.replaceAll("\"","\'"); // sql strings are between ' not "
myJson= "insert into my_table values " + myJson + ";";
```

This will fail if the json has a null attribute and therefore not showing (if x is null the json won't contain x at all, maybe can be changed by config).